# Spring Webclient receives 404 error with no message

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, docker-container, spring-webclient

I have 2 microservices running in separate docker containers in the same network: *attachment-loader-prim* and *attachment-loader-sec*. I call attachment-loader-prim via postman, then some business logic is done and then I want to send request to attachment-loader-sec via Spring Webclient. Data from both services aggregated and returned as a single response. This is what I expect. But Webclient returns me 404 error with no message, so the root cause is not clear. I'm using Spring Weblient like this:

```
suspend fun getData(id: String, params: List<Params>, username: String) {    

    return fetcherWebClientBuilder.build()
            .post()
            .uri("/{id}/attachment", id)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(params)
            .header(usernameHeader, username)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .awaitExchange {
                if (it.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful) {
                    handleSucessCode(it)
                } else it.createExceptionAndAwait().run {
                    LOG.error(this.responseBodyAsString, this)
                    throw ContentProcessingException(this)
                }
            }
}
```

Bean fetcherWebClientBuilder with baseUrl is defined in AppConfig like this:

```
@Bean
fun fetcherWebClientBuilder(): WebClient.Builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://attachment-loader-sec:8086/list")
```

The response is:

```
ERROR 1 {"timestamp":"2021-11-11T13:27:15.396+00:00","path":"/list/25283/attachment","stat
us":404,"error":"Not Found","message":null,"requestId":"25d4ecad-1"}
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$NotFound: 404 Not Found from POST http://attachment-loader-sec:8086/list/25283/attachment
```

Controller, which provides the api is:

```
@Bean
fun mainRouter(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = coRouter {
    "/list/".nest {
        POST("{id}/attachment", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), requestHandler::handleGetAttachment)
 ...}
```

But 404 error is really strange. Here is what I've checked already:

- I use the container name `attachment-loader-sec` (not localhost) to address the container
- Containers are within one network, I checked it with *docker network inspect <network_id>*
- Port was missing, so now I call it as *http://attachment-loader-sec:8086/...*
- Both services are responding via Postman separately.
- I pinged attachment-loader-sec from attachment-loader-prim via *docker exec -ti attachment-loader-prim ping attachment-loader-sec* and get the response messages like *64 bytes from 172.21.0.5: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms*. Which means they can talk to each other.
- My target controller had a GET method, while Webclient was sending a POST request. I made both POST.

Some details:

- Each service has its both ports the same *8086:8086*. Changing the inner port gave nothing.
- Both services are under spring cloud api-gateway with routes configured in routes.yml. And netflix eureka as discovery service - but all that I think is relevant only for outside world.
- Seems like 404 means that target service got the request but for some reason can't respond, right? Anyway, target container logs say nothing about any request.

Any ideas why I can't reach attachment-loader-sec? Any help would be appreciated guys...

Comment: POST("{id}/attachment", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), requestHandler::handleGetAttachment)  --handleGetAttachment-- is that an http "get" request marked as an http POST request?

Comment: If you mean naming - I changed it for security/simplicity, and handleGetAttachment is 1stname which came to my mind. Generally it is a POST request

Comment: ..."I made both POST"... Seems to be the problem, a get request configured as an endpoint should recieve a get a post reciever should recieve a post
a response may be a message by get form the endpoint as configured or it may be a post as configured, changing what the way you send to something that does not conform would make an error. GET can have attachments but is after the ? on the end of the URL , POST is used for data larger than around 1.4 Mega bytes (get req. limitation) in a separate request section, However, that is setup by the programmer NOT automatically.

Comment: Also, can well understand to request data would only require a get, but to recieve it over http if the data is large or by policy, the sender may (potentially) only use "post" and you must then extract and process the post data.